# xml to phpmyadmin creates too many rows

Tags: php, mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

Newbie here and trying to extract "shoedept or ShoeDept, $50, 30%off special,Top quality design,latitude,longitude" from file.xml to a phpmyadmin DB. myTable, which seems stubborn and can't be changed, has the same fields in the same order, except named differently as; type,price,headline,description,latitude,longitude.

```
<source>
<id>shoedept</id>
<name>ShoeDept</name>
</source>
<location>
<address>174 Sioux</address>
<zip>48228</zip>
<citycode>usa:mi:detroit</citycode>
<name>Detroit</name>
<state>MI</state>
<country>USA</country>
<latitude>42.4089</latitude>
<longitude>-82.9432</longitude>
</location>
<images/>
<time>1444207824</time>
<paid>No</paid>
<score>1</score>
<user/>
<url>
http://................
</url>
<attributes>
<features>Leather</features>
<men>1</men>
<women>2</women>
<currency>USD</currency>
<fee>No</fee>
<has_pic>No</has_pic>
<price>50</price>
<price_display>$50</price_display>
</attributes>
</element>
<element>
<id>4030773537</id>
<title>
$50 / special
</title>
<body>
Top quality design
</body>
```

Wen I write this statement;

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "file.xml" INTO TABLE myTable(headline,description.....)
```

I get tons of rows with all the unwanted junk listed. I only want one row from this whole block with the fields listed as columns. When I try to use

```
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<field>';
```

to condense this into one row, it throws an error. Then I tried to create a temp table and force the data into myTable with no hope below;

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "file.xml";
UPDATE tmp SET DEFAULT = 'file.xml';
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

Thanks much

Comment: nitpick: you do **NOT** have a 'phpmyadmin db'. phpmyadmin is a management interface. you have a **mysql database**.

Comment: and `load data infile` is for CSV data. you're not giving it csv, you're giving it xml, which is why there's a `load xml` command... xml != csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INFILE has to be a text file.  Perhaps you can convert it with this tool: 
http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm or something similar.

Then import the .csv file into the database.

As @Marc B mentioned, there is a LOAD XML command (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html).

Comment: Tx 4 help. I initially tried; load xml infile command but kept getting the ERROR 29 "file not found". Then I tried "load data infile", which didn't produce the needed results but at least found the file and executed. After your answer I changed the file to .csv & I'm back to  ERROR 29 "file not found" again. So somehow I'm not having any luck getting the file found. Next, I tried

    load data infile 'file.csv' into table myTable //also tried load data....
    fields terminated by ','
    enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n';

still no luck and get the same not found error. Tx

Comment: I think everybody should be grateful for help in this forum and I'm going to mark this as best answer because it helped me figure out that myTable doesn't want to take most of the file formats. So not knowing anything about sql, my voodoo solution was to simplify the file as much as possible to a .txt, which I don't understand why but it sort of worked better than all other formats so far. There are probably better ways to do this, which I need to keep trying. Thanks again